# Self-Referential Association - Friending Feature in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, social-networking

I am trying to build a simple friending system for a basic social site. I just need my "Wag" link to trigger an action to favorite that current pet to a favorites page for the owner. I followed the [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association?autoplay=true) here to set everything up.

This is the path link I am trying to set up.

```
<% @pets.each do |pet| %>
  <div>
   <%= link_to "Wag", owner_friendships_path(friend_id: owner), method: :post %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

It should go here:

```
<ul>
 <% for friendship in @owner.friendships %>
  <li>
   <%= friendship.friend.name %>
   (<%= link_to "remove", friendship, method: :delete %>)
   </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<p><%= link_to "Find Puppy Pals", pets_path %></p>
```

Routes:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :owners

  resources :pets

  resources :owners do
   resources :pets, shallow: true
   resources :friendships
  end

  root to: "pets#index"
end
```

The relevant schema looks like:

```
create_table "friendships", force: true do |t|
 t.integer  "owner_id"
 t.integer  "friend_id"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "owners", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
 t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
 ...(devise defaults)
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.string   "profile_photo"
end
```

My friendship controller:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @friendships = Friendship.all
 end

 def show
  @friendship = Friendship.find(params[:id])
 end

def create
 @friendship = current_owner.friendships.build(params[:friend_id])
 if @friendship.save
  flash[:notice] = "Added puppy pal."
  redirect_to root_url
 else
  flash[:error] = "Oops, we couldn't save that puppy pal."
  redirect_to root_url
 end
end

def destroy
  @friendship = current_owner.friendships.find(params[:id])
  @friendship.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Removed puppy pal."
  redirect_to root_url
 end
end
```

Pets controller:

```
Class PetsController < ApplicationController

 def index
  @pets = Pet.order("RANDOM()").limit(1)
 end

 def new
  @pet = Pet.new
 end

def create
 @pet = Pet.new(pet_params)
 @pet.owner_id = current_owner.id if current_owner

if @pet.save
  flash[:notice] = 'Your pet profile was saved!'
  redirect_to pets_path
else
  flash.now[:notice] = 'Your pet profile could not be saved.'
  render :new
 end
end

def show
 @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
 @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])
end

def update
 @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])

 if @pet.update(pet_params)
  redirect_to pets_path
 else
  render :edit
 end
end

def destroy
 @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])

 if current_owner == @pet.owner
  @pet.destroy
  redirect_to pets_path
 end
end

private

def pet_params
 params.require(:pet).permit(:name, :breed, :age,
  :color, :weight, :personality, :favorite_things, :owner_id, :profile_photo)
 end
end
```

Pets Table:

```
create_table "pets", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.string   "breed"
 t.integer  "age"
 t.integer  "weight"
 t.text     "personality"
 t.text     "favorite_things"
 t.integer  "owner_id"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.string   "profile_photo"
end
```

Owner Controller:

```
 class OwnersController < ApplicationController
  def show
  @pet = Pet.find(params[:id])
 end

  def edit
   @owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
  end
 end
```

Comment: where are `@pets` defined?

Comment: Updated my post to include the pets controller

Comment: in that case my answer stands - you should be calling `owner_id` on the instance of `pet` in the block

Comment: Can you post your `pets` table?

Comment: I updated with the pets table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line:

```
<%= link_to "Wag", friendships_path(friend_id: owner), method: :post %>
```

to this:

```
<%= link_to "Wag", friendships_path(friend_id: pet.owner_id), method: :post %>
```

`owner` is never defined by itself.  whatever you're calling (I guess it is `owner_id` based on your db model) needs to be called on the instance of `pet` in the block

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed mentioning I do have an owner controller/model.

Comment: based on that, this should still work.  the error is coming from the index action in the pets controller - nothing to do with the owner controller

Comment: Okay, so with that added in and on the correct nested route, it's technically owner_friendships_path instead of friendships_path. With "pet.owner_id", I get `No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"friendships", :friend_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:owner_id]` Without that link_to, pets#index works fine otherwise.

Comment: `pet.owner_id` is correct - maybe you need to change the key name - `friend_id` to `owner_id`

Comment: Changing it from friend_id to owner_id didn't seem to make a difference. However, the route that the friend link should be going to at 'owners/:id/friendships' is telling me that `undefined method `friendships' for nil:NilClass`, so maybe the whole issue is that it's linking to a broken page?

Comment: so the route this is ultimately posting to is friendships#create?  that means that `current_owner` is nil.  why is that?